# Using return result from api requests with Forkjoin with mergeMap and pipe

Tags: rxjs, pipe, observable, fork-join, mergemap

I would like to use return results from multiple api requests and reuse it as a parameter for the second api request and the second api request return a result i have to reuse in the third api request !

The problem is i only can return one api

```
const email = this.credentialsForm.controls['email'].value;


this.http.get('https://drupal_users/index/' + email).pipe(
        map(users => {
            console.log(users);
            const user = users;
            this.userId = user;
            return user;
        }),
        mergeMap(user => {

           const ObservateurCulture = this.http.get('https://index.php/drupal_users/culture/' + email).subscribe((culture: any) => {})

       // Here i wish to reuse "culture" data in another Api call and reuse result again of "Parcelles" api request
          const Parcelles = this.http.get('https://index.php/drupal_users/totherdata/' + culture);

            return forkJoin([ObservateurCulture, Parcelles]);
        }),
        take(1)
    ).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.loading.dismiss();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only result from the last api, `mergeMap` is more than enough for all of the things.

However if you want all of the data combined from the all apis you have to use additionaly `pipe` and `map`

Here's the example snippet!

```js
let userId = -1;
const email = 'test';

const getUser = (email) => rxjs.of(1)
const getCulture = (email) => rxjs.of('en-US')
const getData = (culture) => rxjs.of({
  data: {}
})

const getResultFromLastApi = (email) => {
  getUser(email).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.tap(userId => {
      userId = userId;
    }),
    rxjs.operators.mergeMap(userId => getCulture(email)),
    rxjs.operators.mergeMap(culture => getData(culture)),
    rxjs.operators.take(1)
  ).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}

const getCombinedResult = () => {
  getUser(email).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.tap(userId => {
      userId = userId;
    }),
    rxjs.operators.mergeMap(userId => getCulture(email).pipe(rxjs.operators.map(culture => ({
      userId,
      culture
    })))),
    rxjs.operators.mergeMap(cultureAndUser => getData(cultureAndUser.culture).pipe(rxjs.operators.map(data => ({ ...data,
      ...cultureAndUser
    })))),
    rxjs.operators.take(1)
  ).subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
}

getResultFromLastApi(email);
getCombinedResult(email);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Also

```js
map(users => {
            console.log(users);
            const user = users;
            this.userId = user;
            return user;
        }),
```

I would use `tap` instead of `map` in this section as you are not transforming the data but causing some side-effect in the app ( assign userId somewhere in the app )

```js
tap(userId => {
            console.log(userId);
            this.userId = userId;
        }),
```